# REGEX assistance with nested pattern?

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-replace

I have the following string I need to parse:

```
[QUOTE=Mark]
  [QUOTE=Jack]
    How are you doing Mark?
  [/QUOTE]
 Good to hear from you Jack, Im doing fine!
[/QUOTE]
```

I am basicly trying to convern this set of BBCode into HTML by converting the [quote] areas into stylized DIVs using the following REGEX

```
text = text.replace(/\[QUOTE=(.*?)]([\s\S]*?)\[\/QUOTE\]/gi, '<div class="quotes"><i>Quote by $1</i><br />$2</div>');
```

This code will properly parse out the first set of QUOTES, but not the nested level quotes.  Any ides how I could impprove the expression?

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing it with javascript?

Comment: You'd probably need a recursive approach for this. How about loading your quotes as objects (Quote $author $text $subquotes ...)? You could then output to any format you wish.

Answer (score 4):

If that's all you're doing, the solution is much simpler:

```
text = text.replace(/\[QUOTE=(.*?)\]/gi,
                    '<div class="quotes"><i>Quote by $1</i><br />');
text = text.replace(/\[\/QUOTE\]/gi, '</div>');
```

Your code works too, but you have to apply it multiple times--two in this case, but if there are triply-nested quotes you'll have to make three passes, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

When you get into nested levels you lose the "regular" nature of the input. It becomes more "[context free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar)" like [HTML which is always a hard spot for regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

I suggest you tokenize the string and parse it with somethink like a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Comment: Wouldn't `Atomic Grouping` in `PCRE -PHP` solve the subject (as well?) ? Just curious :)

Comment: @yoda: Not atomic grouping, but it is trivial to parse nested BB in PHP using regex. Thing is, he is using JS (which has far less powerful regexes as far as I remember).